# Is it possible to configure CPanel to run only eith Nginx

Tags: linux, nginx

Is it possible to run Nginx on port 80 along with Cpanel. I want to completely get rid of Apache.

I haven't found only Nginx config's anywhere. I've tried changing config files with some Nginx+Apache plugins, but they didn't work either.

What is the best way to configure this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just get rid of cPanel instead.

Comment: cPanel bad. Shell good. Get an unmanaged VPS if you really want control over that kind of stuff.

Comment: I like the shell stuff. I have been using sites with Nginx and Varnish on Ubuntu. 

But the problem is that Nginx is getting tough with SSL and other addons such as boxbilling.

So i thought CPanel might help. So what do you guys suggest about Nginx, A web interface for just DNS,Filemanager along with shell or something like Control Panel that works with Nginx ?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to serve dynamic content using `nginx` only and CPanel is obviously a dynamic web application. That said, the answer is no, it's not possible.

Comment: I am currently running WordPress sites using and Varnish. So i guess that means dynamic content too.

My config is Nginx on port 8080 and Varnish on port 80. But the problem arises with SSL and other addons.

Comment: There should be an application server behind them, like Apache or PHP-FPM, nginx is only a reverse proxy by nature. It uses HTTP or FastCGI to talk to backends.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry Alex i missed that. i am using PHP-FPM. So is it not possible to use the same kind of config thing to make it work with CPanel..

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I've only used CPanel once and from my experience it's coupled with Apache very tight. So I guess even if it is possible it's not so easy.

Comment: Yeah i dropped out on this one. I guess this can never happen. 

Thanks for your time.